# psql restore sql dump syntax error

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql, restore, yelp

I am trying to import https://www.yelp.com/dataset/documentation/sql into a PostgreSQL instance. It is having problems with accent marks/backtick. Other than doing a character replace, is there any other way to deal with this?

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PaxHeader"
LINE 1: PaxHeader/yelp_db.sql17 uid=998889796
    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ `yelp_db` /*!40100 ...
                                             ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "USE"
LINE 1: USE `yelp_db`;
    ^
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "`"
LINE 1: DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `attribute`;
```

Comment: You are probably using the MySQL code for the Postgres database.  Be sure you have downloaded the correct code.

Comment: They only have one file to download. https://www.yelp.com/dataset/download

Comment: Is there a way to convert MySQL dump to PostgeSQL dump?

Comment: I looked it up, and the script is MySql specific. You will have to convert it into a Postgres script.

Comment: you can load it into mysql, dump as csv & then load it into postgresql

Answer (score 0):

These are typical MySQL syntax issues that PostgreSQL conforms to the standard on and therefore doesn't support.  There are a few different converters on GitHub that might help.  When I had to do this last, there were tools to convert text dumps.  They didn't work perfectly but they got things close enough.  Reviewing the tools around today, they tend to assume you have an actual MySQL database, not just a dump file.

So it looks like the appropriate way to address this today is to load the data into MySQL and then move it to PostgreSQL.  In this regard you seem to have four options that I can think of for converting the schema and data:

1. There are tools to convert XML dumps from MySQL and load these into PostgreSQL.
2. You could set up a foreign data wrapper from PostgreSQL to the MySQL db and then copy the schemas and data in.
3. You could manually convert the schemas, and then dump/reload the data using an ETL process via CSV.
4. There are tools to read a live MySQL database and insert the data into PostgreSQL.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up finding a few of those scripts but ran into little issues as you mentioned. Ended up going down the load in MySQL route.

Comment: You still have the foreign data wrapper approach.  Then moving would be simple.  https://github.com/EnterpriseDB/mysql_fdw

Comment: As alternative to the foreign data wrapper use https://github.com/dimitri/pgloader which imports the data from MySQL to Postgresql